How to find this type of values in Javascript?
I have an object that is like this:
let obj = {
  links: {},
  data: [
    {
      type: "type",
      id: "id",
      attributes: {
        name: "some-name",
      },
    },
    {
      type: "type",
      id: "id",
      attributes: {
        name: "some-other-name",
      },
    },
  ],
};
let array = obj.data;


So I have an object with key and value that is another object, that is in another object that is in array, and that array is in object.
I want to know how to find the exact value, for example I want to find value "some-other-name", how can I do that. I tried with
for (let i in array)
if(array[i].attributes.name === "some-other-name") {
return array[i];

but it seems like it's not working.
Can someone help?

How about doing this in JS:
const result = array.find(item => item.attributes.name === "some-other-name");
if (result) {
  console.log(result.attributes.name);
} else {
  console.log("name not found");
}

Try it here:


// Your code snippet for your object was this"
let obj = {
  links: {},
  data: [
    {
      type: "type",
      id: "id",
      attributes: {
        name: "some-name",
      },
    },
    {
      type: "type",
      id: "id",
      attributes: {
        name: "some-other-name",
      },
    },
  ],
};
let array = obj.data;


// Trying to find the name "some-other-name" from you object

const result = array.find(item => item.attributes.name === "some-other-name");
if (result) {
  console.log(result.attributes.name);
} else {
  console.log("Name not found");
}




I tried this too, but it says "cannot read properties of undefined (reading "name")

You can run the code snippet in my answer. I think, your running them separate, your code snippet and the block
const result = array.find(item => item.attributes.name === "some-other-name");
if (result) {
console.log(result.attributes.name);
} else {
console.log("Name not found");
}
Hence, the attributes.name is undefined.
